# Flexible mixing of multiple aggregations in data.table for different column combinations

Tags: r, data.table

The following problem prevents me so far from a really flexible usage of data.table aggregations.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(C1=c("a","b","b"),
                 C2=round(rnorm(4),4),
                 C3=1:12,
                 C4=9:12)

sum_cols <- c("C2","C3")

#I want to apply a custom aggregation over multiple columns
DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=C1,.SDcols=sum_cols]

### Part 1 of question ###
#but what if I want to add another aggregation, e.g. count
DT[,.N,by=C1]

#this is not working as intended (creates 4 rows instead of 2 and doesnt contain sum_cols)
DT[,.(.N,lapply(.SD,sum)),by=C1,.SDcols=sum_cols]

### Part 2 of question ###
# or another function for another set of colums and adding a prefix to keep them appart?
mean_cols <- c("C3","C4")

#intended table structure (with 2 rows again)
C1 sum_C2 sum_C3 mean_C3 mean_C4
```

I know I can always merge various single aggregation results by some key but I`m sure there must be a correct, flexible and easy way to do what I would like to do (especially Part 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that data.table's `j` argument expects a list output, which can be built with `c`, as mentioned in @akrun's answer. Here are two ways to do it:

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(C1=c("a","b","b"), C2=round(rnorm(4),4), C3=1:12, C4=9:12)
sum_cols <- c("C2","C3")
mean_cols <- c("C3","C4")

# with the development version, 1.10.1+
DT[, c(
  .N, 
  sum = lapply(.SD[, ..sum_cols], sum), 
  mean = lapply(.SD[, ..mean_cols], mean)
), by=C1]

# in earlier versions
DT[, c(
  .N, 
  sum = lapply(.SD[, sum_cols, with=FALSE], sum), 
  mean = lapply(.SD[, mean_cols, with=FALSE], mean)
), by=C1]
```

`mget` returns a list and `c` connects elements together to make a list.

---

*Comments*

If you turn on the `verbose` data.table option for these calls, you'll see a message:

> The result of j is a named list. It's very inefficient to create the same names over and over again for each group. When j=list(...), any names are detected, removed and put back after grouping has completed, for efficiency. Using j=transform(), for example, prevents that speedup (consider changing to :=). This message may be upgraded to warning in future.

Also, you'll see that the optimized group mean and sum are not being used (see `?GForce` for details). We can get around this [by following FAQ 1.6](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#ok-but-i-dont-know-the-expressions-in-advance.-how-do-i-programatically-pass-them-in) perhaps, but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Great, thank you - this will make my life with dt much easier and convenient. Performance comes second (in this case) -  I will check your remarks if I run into issues. I am surprised though, that the .SDcols is not so helpful here... it seems rather limited in general then.

Comment: @katsumi Yeah, .SDcols is just for one set of cols at a time, so if you want multiple (possibly overlapping) sets, it won't be so useful, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The output are `list`s, so we use `c` to concatenate both the `list` outputs

```
DT[,c(.N,lapply(.SD,sum)),by=C1,.SDcols=sum_cols]
#    C1 N    C2 C3
# 1:  a 4 0.288 22
# 2:  b 8 0.576 56
```

Comment: Thank you, that really solves the first part of the question. Any ideas for the second part, where I want to have different aggregations for different sets of columns (ideally with some aggegration dependent naming scheme for output columns)?